# How to create notes in iPhone notes app programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, store

I have some data in my local database in my iPhone app.

I want to programmatically create a note in iPhones notes app and store this data.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently not possible as there are no known APIs for working with the Notes application.